# Looking for the title of a "forgotten land" young adult book from the early '60's

Tags: story-identification

When I was a kid I read and re-read a YA novel, set in the Andes, about siblings who crawl through a tunnel and find a valley where dinosaurs and cave people co-exist.  I believe it was published in the late '50's or early '60's.  Obviously pretty much taken whole cloth from  Doyle's "The Lost World," and, in retrospect it was a badly plotted book, but I loved it back then.  Still,  I'd like to have the name again.

Two parts I remember are 1) a boy crawling through the tunnel in the beginning and finding a freshly killed archaeopteryx, and 2) the youngest toddling around saying "pleasure's yours" instead of plesiosaurus.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I remember that book, there was a large cavern with glowing gas at the roof, and a large lake with a plesiosaur in the lake. At the end of the book, there was a volcanic eruption, and the kids and the cavemen had to go into the cave with the lake, and the lake ended up draining out through cracks in the cave floor, and the kids ended up exploring the cracks, got lost, and that's how they ended back in the outside world. And no, I don't remember the name of the book either.

Comment: Yes! That's the one - boy, are you bringing back memories.  Thanks.

Comment: This is not what you are looking for, but someone looking for something similar might be looking for *Journey to the Beginning of Time* which is a 1950s movie made into televised shorts in the 1960s. There is a Wikipedia entry for it.

Answer (score 5):

[Adventure in Forgotten Valley](https://openlibrary.org/works/OL6660976W/Adventure_in_Forgotten_Valley) by Glyn Frewer :)

> This young adult fiction story is set in South America. Five Children
>   of varying ages get separated from their local guide when a cave in
>   occurs in the passage they just explored. While trying to find another
>   way out the children discover a lost valley where time stopped in the
>   era of Dinosaurs. Their journey and trials make for a very exciting
>   and entertaining adventure as they battle dinosaurs, and work to
>   survive on their trek back to their families.

Comment: Smooshie, you are a life-saver.  It's been nagging at me for a long time.  Thank you, thank you!!!

Comment: @rws Would you mind marking the answer as "accepted" if this was the book you were looking for?